# Changing Coordinate Origin [From Coord System A -> Coord System B]

Tags: 2d, rotation, coordinates, position

I'd really appreciate some help on this one.

Given 2 coordinate systems A and B where

1. xA is an initial Vector3 position, rA is an initial Quaternion rotation
2. xB is an initial Vector3 position, rB is an initial Quaternion rotation

How can I then transform a random (position, rotation) from A into B?

I can understand how I would go about if I only had position. If I had randomA, it would be
*randomB = xB + (randomA - xA)* to shift from **A to B**. I'm kind of stuck on where should I incorporate the quaternions / their inverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe something like this should work:

```
random_position_world = (Quat_A * random_position_A) + xA_world
random_position_B = inverse(Quat_B) * (random_position_world - xB_world)

random_rotation_world = Quat_A * random_rotation_A
random_rotation_B = inverse(Quat_B) * random_rotation_world
```

The suffix `_world` here is to denote that the value is expressed in world space. If you want a bit more insight into this sort of thing you should read about [transformation matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix).

Comment: Meaning that the Quat_x, random_position_x are in local space?

Comment: The position, yes. Quat_x is suposed to be the rotation of the coordinate system X with respect to the world's.

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks! Will look more into it, thanks for the link!

Comment: To clarify, this works when world space is common for the two coordinate systems, right? Or does this work when xA, rA - xB, rB come from different world spaces?

Comment: Yeah, "World" space is supposed to be the same for all of them. If xA and xB are expressed in different coordinate systems you would need to convert between those as well. That kind of thing is where using matrices becomes super convenient, because concatenating space conversions just becomes multiplying matrices together. If you have the time to go through it, 3Blue1Brown's [linear algebra series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kYB8IZa5AuE&list=PLZHQObOWTQDPD3MizzM2xVFitgF8hE_ab&index=3) is the best explanation of all this stuff that I have seen.

Comment: I've watched it once, but constantly seem to forget it. And I just realized I posed the wrong question. What I essentially was searching for is: xA,rA and xB,rB represent the same position and rotation (in world space) from two unknown world coordinate systems. Having those initial conditions, can I transform a random_xA, random_rA to random_xB, random_rB? Should I edit the question or post another one?

Comment: Oh, I see. I believe that should be posted as a different question.